# ASP.NET AcessDataSource and dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, datasource, data-binding

I'm using visual studio 2008 with .net 3.5.
I have an AccessDataSource that is linked to a access database.  I have a dropdownlist that use the AccessDataSource.  Everything was done with the wizard and everything was working just fine.

At the page load I decided to call the SelectedIndexChanged of my dropdownlist to update something with the selectedValue but to my suprise the selectedValue was an empty string.

To resolve the problem I put this in my page_load
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then

```
        ddlAnniversaire.DataBind()
        ddlAnniversaire_SelectedIndexChanged(Nothing, Nothing)
    End If

End Sub
```

If I don't put ddlAnniversaire.DataBind() the ddlAnniversaire.selectedValue is "" in my method.  Why?
Normally when is the ddlAnniversaire.DataBind() called?

Thanks

Comment: If you just wan´t to select something in your ddl list you could use: SelectedIndex = 0 or SelectedValue = "Your value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataBind() event occurs after the Page_Load and in the PreRender event of the [Page Lifecycle (MSDN link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Hope this helps,
JP

Comment: Is it ok to call the DataBing() in the Page_Load has I did?
Is it going to be called twice?

Comment: After some testing I found that sometimes it's called twice, but I can't isolate why.

Comment: To pre-select an item, you can just set the SelectedIndex of the DDL in the OnRender event of the page or handle the Load event of the DDL.